# Entity Framework - SaveChanges throwing error about different table. Cannot be NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Currently messing about with Entity Framework alongside an ASP.NET API. I am coming to an error which I cannot solve. I have created a controller which inserts a User model into a database for creating a new user. This model takes in a username, passwordHash, passwordSalt, email. This is all working fine as expected and is posting to the database and saving transactions properly through EF.

I then have another controller which makes use of the same DbContext and is used for posting to a different table within the same SQL DB. It only makes use of a basic model with two fields, both of which are strings. However when I attempt to invoke SaveChanges() in EF on the dbContext for this class I am getting an error about a field within the User model being null (passwordHash, passwordSalt). Am I missing something here? I am trying to use SaveChanges on a completely different model and table within the database and its throwing an error relating to the Users table which is not being posted to?

Can someone please advise, I have looked about at other answers relating to the transaction history but this does not seem be a the issue. There is no relationship between the two tables. Each has a PK set to the UserId (Users) and ControllerDescriptionId (Other model) which are auto incrementing Ids and not required to be assigned.

**Users model and insert**

```
public class Users
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public int Group { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public Users Create(Users user, string password)
        {
            byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            _dbContext.Users.Add(user);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return user;
        }
```

**Other Model and insert**

```
public class ControllerDescription
    {
        public int ControllerDescriptionID { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public bool AddGroupToController(ControllerDescription controllerDescription)
        {
            _dbContext.ControllerDescription.Add(controllerDescription);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

I have added the barebone methods and removed any code which is not causing issues in the snippets above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a relationship defined between the other table and the Users? What does the entity you're trying to save look like? It sounds to me like youre trying to wire up a relationship from one to the other by providing an incomplete User object that represents an existing user, and EF is taking it as a new User and trying to insert it

Comment: @CaiusJard I have added some additional info and code to above. There is no relationship between the two tables or models in any way.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you make a new context inside AddGroupToController? eg `AddGroupToController(ControllerDescription controllerDescription){ var db = new MyWhateverContext(); db.ControllerDescription.Add(controllerDescription); db.SaveChanges();}` ?